# JavaScript code with If Statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have been working on a text based game for personal use to get better at JavaScript. With this game, the user answers the questions that is written (like a story/choice game). This is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="gamescript.js"></script>-->

<style>
body {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

#mspace {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.hideThis {
  display: none;
}

button {
  margin: 10px;
}

</style>


<script>

function myFunction(){
    var door = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    if (door == "Door 1" || door == "door 1"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
    }else if (door == "Door 2" || door == "door 2"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You must enter a door!"
    }
}

function myFunction2(){
    var choice1 = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
    if (choice1 == "enter passageway" || choice1 == "passageway"){
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You entered the" + choice1;
     }else if (choice1 == "continue searching"){
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You " + choice1;    
    }else{
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You must choose an option!"
    }
}

// JS for BOSS level
// starting variable for the boss
var stamina = 10;

// starting message
var msg = "A huge, threatening monster wants to fight you! What do you do?";
// run a function that is below
document.getElementById("mspace")

// click a button to execute a function
// NOTE: no parentheses after the function name in these cases
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("fight").onclick = fightResponse;
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = runResponse;
}

function runResponse() {
  if (stamina > 8) {
    msg = "The monster swings his long arm and -- GAME OVER!";
    hideButtons();
  } else if (stamina > 3) {
    msg = "Well, that's one way to end a fight ...";
    hideButtons();
  } else {
    msg = "Keep fighting! The monster is almost dead!";
  }
  writeMessage();
}

function fightResponse() {
  if (stamina > 8) {
    msg = "The monster is strong! It resists your attack!";
  } else if (stamina > 5) {
    msg = "With a loud screech, the monster stands firm.";
  } else if (stamina > 3) {
    msg = "Your attack seems to be having an effect! The monster stumbles!";
  } else if (stamina > 0) {
    msg = "This monster is about to fall! It staggers and reels!";
  } else {
    msg = "With a final swing! The monster has been defeated! You have triumphed!";
    hideButtons();
  }
  // create new random number from 0 to 5
  var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  // subtract it from stamina
  stamina -= damage;
  writeMessage();
}

function hideButtons() {
  // changes the class on the div - see the CSS pane 
  document.getElementById("game").className = "hideThis";
}

window.onload = function writeMessage() {
  // write message into the yellow paragraph
  document.getElementById("mspace").innerHTML = msg;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<p id ="door"> Which door do you wish to enter? Door 1 or Door 2? </p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<!---- Question 1 ---->
<p id ="choice1">Behind Door 1 is an empty room. Whilst searching the room for clues, you see a hidden passageway. Do you wish to enter the passageway or continue searching?</p>

<input id="myInput2" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Enter</button>


<!---- Boss ---->
<h1>Fight the Monster!</h1>

<p id="mspace"></p>

<div id="game">

  <button id="fight">Fight</button>
  <button id="run">Run</button>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

When the questions appear, although it does what I want it to, I wanted it so that when the user enters either "Door 1" or "Door 2" for the first question, the 2nd question to appear after it. In my code, it's like a list of questions with text box underneath. It doesn't look nice and I don't know how to change it.

For the "Final Boss" code, It doesn't seem to be working and i don't know why. I have checked the F12 developer tool and no errors are showing.

All the help is appreciated and thank you!

Comment: So what do you want to do with your code, exactly?

Comment: Where's css file

Comment: Added in the CSS code. I have said what I'd like to happen. When the first question is answered, I wanted the 2nd question to appear after it and the 1st question to go, instead of like a list of questions. And the final Boss code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because browsers generally process code (HTML, CSS, or Javascript) from the top down, `window.onload`is used to ensure that a function is executed after the entire page has been loaded which helps avoid reference errors. However, in your code, `window.onload` is assigned multiple times, which means that only the last assignment will get executed. You can remedy this by consolidating all of your `onload` functionality into one 'parent' function, or by something like this which allows you to append functions to the `onload` event (more information can be found [here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/index.html)):

```
function addLoadEvent(func) 
{ 
      var oldonload = window.onload; 
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') { 
        window.onload = func; 
      } else { 
        window.onload = function() { 
          if (oldonload) { 
            oldonload(); 
          } 
          func(); 
        } 
      } 
} 
addLoadEvent(nameOfSomeFunctionToRunOnPageLoad); 
addLoadEvent(function() { 
      /* more code to run on page load */ 
    });
```

When it comes to displaying the questions sequentially, as suggested by @KKK you may want to look into the visibility attribute and set it accordingly. But if you want more dynamic functionality, then you will want to use `document.getElementById()` and its related functions to edit, append, and remove elements on the page. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp) should be a good starting point.

As an aside, be careful when putting multiple conditions in `if` statements. Your code should function fine due to [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), but proper use of parentheses can ensure that it functions as intended while improving code readability.

Comment: Thank you for the information, explained and helped a lot! When I try to run @KKK's code that they kindly fixed for me in Notepad++, it doesn't run. It's showing as a blank HTML document. I separated the HTML and JS and linked the JS to HTML in the header but doesn't work

Comment: @Mikey Are you running it on a web server like *WAMP*, or are you running it as a file? If you're running it as a file, browsers are very picky about allowing file system access from html code because that would be a huge security vulnerability. If you are running it on a web server, linking to the script with a relative path should work just fine, but if you're running it from a file, then you'll end up running into some issues and may just want to temporarily put all your code into the same file.

Comment: @Mikey Also, when I run his code, I get an `Uncaught TypeError` which is, in this case, clearly the result of trying to reference page elements that have not yet been loaded. I would recommend putting the first three lines of his javascript code in a function assigned to the `window.onload` event to avoid those types of problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! I have added in the window.onload event and it has worked but getting a new error now "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". at this code "// starting message
var msg = "A huge, threatening monster wants to fight you! What do you do?";
// run a function that is below
document.getElementById("mspace").innerHTML = msg;" I have searched online and people are saying add in a window.onload. I added that in and it's working but the questions are appearing as a list and not appearing after you added in your choice :(

Comment: @Mikey Your first problem is that `document.getElementById` is trying to find an element that has not yet been loaded, and therefore returns null. You cannot access properties of null, because null has none; it is nothing.  That's why you put it in the `window.onload` event. Doing so ensures that every element is loaded before the code is run. As for your second problem, you will need to write your own javascript code that dynamically updates the webpage. More information on this can be found in the second link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have got to stop putting "window.onload" before things...
Maybe this example has a more desired effect..

Also a good coding practice is to put your content scripts just before the closing body tag. They you won't have so many onload issues.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var door = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    if (door == "Door 1" || door == "door 1"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
    }else if (door == "Door 2" || door == "door 2"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You must enter a door!"
    }
}

function myFunction2(){
    var choice1 = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
    if (choice1 == "enter passageway" || choice1 == "passageway"){
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You entered the" + choice1;
     }else if (choice1 == "continue searching"){
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You " + choice1;    
    }else{
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You must choose an option!"
    }
}

// JS for BOSS level
// starting variable for the boss
var stamina = 10;

// starting message
var msg = "A huge, threatening monster wants to fight you! What do you do?";
// run a function that is below

// click a button to execute a function
// NOTE: no parentheses after the function name in these cases

document.getElementById("fight").onclick = fightResponse;
document.getElementById("run").onclick = runResponse;

function runResponse() {
  if (stamina > 8) {
    msg = "The monster swings his long arm and -- GAME OVER!";
    hideButtons();
  } else if (stamina > 3) {
    msg = "Well, that's one way to end a fight ...";
    hideButtons();
  } else {
    msg = "Keep fighting! The monster is almost dead!";
  }
  writeMessage();
}

function fightResponse() {
  if (stamina > 8) {
    msg = "The monster is strong! It resists your attack!";
  } else if (stamina > 5) {
    msg = "With a loud screech, the monster stands firm.";
  } else if (stamina > 3) {
    msg = "Your attack seems to be having an effect! The monster stumbles!";
  } else if (stamina > 0) {
    msg = "This monster is about to fall! It staggers and reels!";
  } else {
    msg = "With a final swing! The monster has been defeated! You have triumphed!";
    hideButtons();
  }
  // create new random number from 0 to 5
  var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  // subtract it from stamina
  stamina -= damage;
  writeMessage();
}

function hideButtons() {
  // changes the class on the div - see the CSS pane 
  document.getElementById("game").className = "hideThis";
}

function writeMessage() {
  // write message into the yellow paragraph
  document.getElementById("mspace").innerHTML = msg;
}
writeMessage();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="gamescript.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>

<p id ="door"> Which door do you wish to enter? Door 1 or Door 2? </p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<!---- Question 1 ---->
<p id ="choice1">Behind Door 1 is an empty room. Whilst searching the room for clues, you see a hidden passageway. Do you wish to enter the passageway or continue searching?</p>

<input id="myInput2" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Enter</button>


<!---- Boss ---->
<h1>Fight the Monster!</h1>

<p id="mspace"></p>

<div id="game">

  <button id="fight">Fight</button>
  <button id="run">Run</button>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. When I was using the F12 developer tool, i was copying the error messages to Google and other people had same problem, most were saying use the "window.onload" so I did and the errors went

Comment: How can I make it so, when the first question is chosen and the user clicks "Enter" for the second question to show/pop -up and the first question to disappear, where as, in my code when it's run, it's showing as a list of the questions

Answer (score 0):

You need to set visibility `hidden` and `visible` for the particular elements as necessary.
For your second problem, you should not create the writeMessage function on `window.onload`. Here is the updated code with some other formatting corrections.

```js
document.getElementById("choice1").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("question2").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("question3").style.visibility = "hidden";

function myFunction(){
    var door = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    if (door == "Door 1" || door == "door 1"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered " + door;
        document.getElementById("choice1").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("question2").style.visibility = "visible";
    }else if (door == "Door 2" || door == "door 2"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered " + door;
        document.getElementById("choice1").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("question2").style.visibility = "visible";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You must enter a door!"
    }
}

function myFunction2(){
    var choice1 = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
    if (choice1 == "enter passageway" || choice1 == "passageway"){
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You entered the " + choice1;
        document.getElementById("question3").style.visibility = "visible";
     }else if (choice1 == "continue searching"){
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You " + choice1; 
        document.getElementById("question3").style.visibility = "visible";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You must choose an option!"
    }
}

// JS for BOSS level
// starting variable for the boss
var stamina = 10;

// starting message
var msg = "A huge, threatening monster wants to fight you! What do you do?";
// run a function that is below
document.getElementById("mspace").innerHTML = msg;

// click a button to execute a function
// NOTE: no parentheses after the function name in these cases
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("fight").onclick = fightResponse;
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = runResponse;
}

function runResponse() {
  if (stamina > 8) {
    msg = "The monster swings his long arm and -- GAME OVER!";
    hideButtons();
  } else if (stamina > 3) {
    msg = "Well, that's one way to end a fight ...";
    hideButtons();
  } else {
    msg = "Keep fighting! The monster is almost dead!";
  }
  writeMessage();
}

function fightResponse() {
  if (stamina > 8) {
    msg = "The monster is strong! It resists your attack!";
  } else if (stamina > 5) {
    msg = "With a loud screech, the monster stands firm.";
  } else if (stamina > 3) {
    msg = "Your attack seems to be having an effect! The monster stumbles!";
  } else if (stamina > 0) {
    msg = "This monster is about to fall! It staggers and reels!";
  } else {
    msg = "With a final swing! The monster has been defeated! You have triumphed!";
    hideButtons();
  }
  // create new random number from 0 to 5
  var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  // subtract it from stamina
  stamina -= damage;
  writeMessage();
}

function hideButtons() {
  // changes the class on the div - see the CSS pane 
  document.getElementById("game").className = "hideThis";
}

function writeMessage() {
  document.getElementById("mspace").innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<p id ="door"> Which door do you wish to enter? Door 1 or Door 2? </p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<!---- Question 1 ---->
<p id ="choice1">Behind Door 1 is an empty room. Whilst searching the room for clues, you see a hidden passageway. Do you wish to enter the passageway or continue searching?</p>

<div id="question2">
<input id="myInput2" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Enter</button>
</div>


<!---- Boss ---->
<div id="question3">
<h1>Fight the Monster!</h1>

<p id="mspace"></p>

<div id="game">

  <button id="fight">Fight</button>
  <button id="run">Run</button>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so sooo much!! appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Your code works here but when I add it to Notepad++, it's not working, can't seem to figure out why. I have separated the HTML and JS and linked them but showing a blank HTML